# C++ - CString not sure what value to set for dumping html source

Tags: c++, html

I am trying to do the following:

Firstly, I dump a HTML source of a page about 1000-2000 lines of code.

Next, I want to do this

```
ifstream myfile;

myfile.open("file.txt");
while(!myfile.eof())
{
    getline(myfile,sline);
    sdata = sdata + sline;
}
```

However I don't want to use `string` for my case, how do I use cstring to hold `sdata`. In this case, `sdata` is a `string`, but I want to hold the content using cstring. Is there a way for me to initialize and use cstring instead? It's a non functional requirement for my mini project.

Comment: Not sure what the problem is. You want to use a CString instead of a std::string to put the contents of the file in? Then why don't you? Also, is there a reason for reading the file line by line instead of the whole file at once?

Comment: How do i read the whole thing at once?

Comment: That is answered all around the web. [Here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vclanguage/thread/d2543911-4cc4-44d8-8494-28509ff4d614) for instance. `CString str;

CFile file;

if(file.Open(name, CFile::modeRead))

{

  int len = file.GetLength();

  file.Read(str.GetBuffer(len), len);

  str.ReleaseBuffer();

}`

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, `sline` has to be a `std::string`, but nothing should prevents you from having `sdata` as a `CString`:

```
CString sdata;
#ifdef _UNICODE
std::wstring sline;
#else
std::string sline;
#endif
while(getline(myfile, sline))
{
    sdata += sline.c_str();
}
```

That takes the raw `char *` and append it to the `CString` object.